# Shell script with CGI works fine with bash but not with sh

Tags: linux, bash, cgi, embedded-linux, sh

I have found following working example of CGI with bash. If I change first two lines to

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
```

following the script stops working and when I browse the script in a browser the 'foo', 'bar' and 'foobar' declared at the bottom of the script disappears.

Any idea how can I make the same example work with sh. Actually I need to run such an example over an embedded device where I don't have bash but sh.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
echo "
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://${HTTP_HOST}:${SERVER_PORT}${SCRIPT_NAME}?foo=1234" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="bar">
<textarea name="foobar"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>"


# (internal) routine to store POST data
cgi_get_POST_vars()
{
    # check content type
    # FIXME: not sure if we could handle uploads with this..
    [ "${CONTENT_TYPE}" != "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ] && \
    echo "Warning: you should probably use MIME type "\
         "application/x-www-form-urlencoded!" 1>&2
    # save POST variables (only first time this is called)
    [ -z "$QUERY_STRING_POST" \
      -a "$REQUEST_METHOD" = "POST" -a ! -z "$CONTENT_LENGTH" ] && \
    read -n $CONTENT_LENGTH QUERY_STRING_POST
    return
}

# (internal) routine to decode urlencoded strings
cgi_decodevar()
{
    [ $# -ne 1 ] && return
    local v t h
    # replace all + with whitespace and append %%
    t="${1//+/ }%%"
    while [ ${#t} -gt 0 -a "${t}" != "%" ]; do
    v="${v}${t%%\%*}" # digest up to the first %
    t="${t#*%}"       # remove digested part
    # decode if there is anything to decode and if not at end of string
    if [ ${#t} -gt 0 -a "${t}" != "%" ]; then
        h=${t:0:2} # save first two chars
        t="${t:2}" # remove these
        v="${v}"`echo -e \\\\x${h}` # convert hex to special char
    fi
    done
    # return decoded string
    echo "${v}"
    return
}

# routine to get variables from http requests
# usage: cgi_getvars method varname1 [.. varnameN]
# method is either GET or POST or BOTH
# the magic varible name ALL gets everything
cgi_getvars()
{
    [ $# -lt 2 ] && return
    local q p k v s
    # get query
    case $1 in
    GET)
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING}&"
        ;;
    POST)
        cgi_get_POST_vars
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING_POST}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING_POST}&"
        ;;
    BOTH)
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING}&"
        cgi_get_POST_vars
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING_POST}" ] && q="${q}${QUERY_STRING_POST}&"
        ;;
    esac
    shift
    s=" $* "
    # parse the query data
    while [ ! -z "$q" ]; do
    p="${q%%&*}"  # get first part of query string
    k="${p%%=*}"  # get the key (variable name) from it
    v="${p#*=}"   # get the value from it
    q="${q#$p&*}" # strip first part from query string
    # decode and evaluate var if requested
    [ "$1" = "ALL" -o "${s/ $k /}" != "$s" ] && \
        eval "$k=\"`cgi_decodevar \"$v\"`\""
    done
    return
}



# register all GET and POST variables
cgi_getvars BOTH ALL

echo "<pre>foo=$foo</pre>"
echo "<pre>bar=$bar</pre>"
echo "<pre>foobar=$foobar</pre>"

echo "</body>
</html>"
```

**Update 1:**
`sh -x script` returned following:

```
+ echo Content-type: text/html\n\n
Content-type: text/html


+ echo 
<html>
<body>
<form action=http://:?foo=1234 method=POST>
<input type=text name=bar>
<textarea name=foobar></textarea>
<input type=submit>
</form>

<html>
<body>
<form action=http://:?foo=1234 method=POST>
<input type=text name=bar>
<textarea name=foobar></textarea>
<input type=submit>
</form>
+ cgi_getvars BOTH ALL
+ [ 2 -lt 2 ]
+ local q p k v s
+ [ ! -z  ]
+ cgi_get_POST_vars
+ [  != application/x-www-form-urlencoded ]
+ echo Warning: you should probably use MIME type  application/x-www-form-urlencoded!
Warning: you should probably use MIME type  application/x-www-form-urlencoded!
+ [ -z  -a  = POST -a ! -z  ]
+ return
+ [ ! -z  ]
+ shift
+ s= ALL 
+ [ ! -z  ]
+ return
+ echo <pre>foo=</pre>
<pre>foo=</pre>
+ echo <pre>bar=</pre>
<pre>bar=</pre>
+ echo <pre>foobar=</pre>
<pre>foobar=</pre>
+ echo </body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `/bin/sh` is still some kind of shell, which you need to determine before doing any changes. what does `sh --version` say?

Comment: @baltusaj Did you try running the script in debug mode? You can do so by running it `sh -x scriptname.sh`. Change the `sha-bang` line to `Bourne Shell` and run it in debug mode. It might throw in some info which can be useful.

Comment: /bin/sh --version, and sh --verion returns 'sh: Illegal Operation --' error. Same error occurs if run it in the sh shell. I executed the sh shell by running /bin/sh in the default bash shell.

Comment: Can't see any useful information in the displayed debug info. For viewing the data displayed, please check the Update 1 in the question.

Comment: Cgi scripts should properly output the HTTP headers with CRLF line terminators. Your `sh` may not support `"\r\n"` in `echo`, maybe try `echo -e` and/or `printf` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash has lots of extensions compared to POSIX specification and your script is using some of them. Your `/bin/sh` apparently isn't bash (might be ash, dash, mksh or something) and does not have those extensions. You'll have to go through the script and check each construct against documentation of your sh or the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/toc.html).

Quckly looking:

- `function cgi_get_POST_vars()`: The function keyword shouldn't be there and the opening brace should go on the same line.
- `read -n $CONTENT_LENGTH QUERY_STRING_POST`: read (shell builtin) does not have -n option in POSIX.
- `t="${1//+/ }%%"`, `h=${t:0:2}`: Bourne does not support either of these modifiers.

but there may be some more.

Edit:

- `echo` is the most incompatible command between shells. The standard just says behaviour with `\` is implementation-defined. You have to use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Function declarations with the `function` keyword are not compatible with Bourne scripts. The correct syntax for `sh` is

```
cgi_get_POST_vars() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But that din solve the main problem. Browser is still not showing 'foo', 'bar' and 'foobar' values.

Comment: @baltusaj: Yes, there are some more non-POSIX features used in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Also be very careful with scripts like this. This argument parser is susceptible to a shell-injection attack. For instance, if a variable is passed:

```
cgi-bin/myscript.cgi&foo=bar`ls`bar
```

I believe that the "ls" command will be executed during the argument decode. And you can imagine a lot more destructive commands than "ls". Also consider what will happen if the argument `&PATH=""` passed by a hostile user. This stuff is tough to get right and if you're dealing with an embedded device, I wouldn't be at all surprised if the web server is running with root privileges.